# time-dependent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory

A free particle of spin 1 is at rest in a magnetic field B, so that
$$ H_0 = −κ B_z S_z $$
where $S_z$ is the projection of the spin operator in the z direction. A harmonic perturbation
with frequency $ ω = κ B_z $ is applied in the x direction for a short time (one period of
oscillation only), so that the weak perturbation is
$$ V (t) = −κ B_x S_x sin(ωt) \quad  \text{for} \quad 0 < t < T = (2π/ω) $$
Calculate, using time-dependent perturbation theory the probability of observing $S_z = ℏ$ to the lowest non-vanishing order.

So I have the solution here and trying to understand what happened at the beginning of the second row! How did we get the exponential $e^{i(\omega_m - \omega_0 ) t' }$ ?

[image]

Comment: Don't use images for equations (and text). Use MathJax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the fact that $|m\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$ are states with definite energy $\omega_m$ and $\omega_0$ respectively. Hence
$$\hat{H}_0|m\rangle=\omega_m|m\rangle\Rightarrow
e^{i\hat{H}_0 t'}|m\rangle=e^{i\omega_m t'}|m\rangle$$
$$\hat{H}_0|m\rangle=\omega_0|m\rangle\Rightarrow
e^{i\hat{H}_0 t'}|m\rangle=e^{i\omega_0 t'}|m\rangle$$
where the exponentials in the right hand side of the equations above do not contain any operators in their exponent...